# Is it possible to freeze an app in Bluestacks?

Tags: bluestacks

Sometimes is beneficial to "freeze" an application, for example when configuring on-screen controls for a game which doesn't display them at all times. Hotkey would be the most convenient.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? I'm going to assume Windows. I have no real experience with Bluestacks itself, but you can try suspending the whole process. To test if it can work open the `Resource Monitor`, right-click the Bluestacks process and click `Suspend process`.

If it does manage to 'pause' the app you can work on making it programmable using perhaps [PsSuspend](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend) provided as part of PsTools. Finally put it into something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Usage:
`pssuspend <process name | process id>` (`-r` to resume)

Comment: Windows. I considered suspending the process, but then I can't access Bluestack's on-screen GUI options? There's also [Universal Pause Button](https://github.com/ryanries/UniversalPauseButton) for Windows — I don't think this method will work for my usage case unfortunately.

Comment: If you know a way to suspend apps on Android (without root) that should be a viable solution.